# SQL joining and counting 3 tables and including NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, sql-order-by

[Link to relevant schema in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOFoN.png)

For SQL. Making a query to show **All** employees who have helped customers and showing the count of their invoices. My issue was that I could get employees count and ID to show, but I could not get ALL employees to show from the query.

Output should look something like

ID - Last - First - COUNT(invoices)

Name should show up if NULL as well.

I tried:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId,e.LastName, e.FirstName, COUNT() as NUM_INVOICE
FROM employees AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers as c ON e.EmployeeId=c.SupportRepId
INNER JOIN invoices as i ON c.CustomerId =i.CustomerId
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId
ORDER BY NUM_INVOICE DESC
```

And it gave : [Output from my best attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrJOJ.png)

**The problem was** that this did not show the remaining id's that did not have any invoices connected through the customers table and to the invoices table. It is missing 5 names from the employee table and they should show NULL for the count. I would think that a Left inner join would solve this and "bring" the names from the employees table but they are dropped.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your last jon needs to be a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Explain why you expect what you expect, with reference to language documentation/definition. [mre] Put what is needed to ask in your post. Use text, not images/links, for what can be given as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem was that this did not show the remaining id's that did not have any invoices connected through the customers table and to the invoices table.

Then, use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    e.EmployeeId, e.LastName, e.FirstName, COUNT(i.CustomerId) AS NUM_INVOICE
FROM employees AS e
LEFT JOIN customers AS c ON e.EmployeeId = c.SupportRepId
LEFT JOIN invoices AS i ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId
ORDER BY NUM_INVOICE DESC
```

Comment: And change `COUNT(*)`  to `COUNT(i.InvoiceId)` so as not to count zero invoices as 1 (i.e. not count the outer joined empty invoice).

Comment: This got very close to the expected solution! I had put 2 LEFT JOIN in the problem just like you have it but I scrapped it because I was getting a count of 1 instead of 0. I hadn't put 'COUNT(i.CustomerId)', I was just using COUNT(), so even if I had the extra few rows from the customer table it would still show a 1 instead of 0. The results should show a NULL.

Comment: @Michael Racz: If you want null instead of zero, use `NULLIF(COUNT(i.CustomerId), 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an alternative: I prefer aggregating data before joining it. Here, I would join the invoice count to the employees:

```
select e.employeeid, e.lastname, e.firstname, coalesce(ic.cnt, 0) as num_invoice
from employees as e
left outer join
(
  select c.supportrepid, count(*) as cnt
  from customers as c 
  inner join invoices as i on i.customerid = c.customerid
  group by c.supportrepid
) ic on ic.supportrepid = e.employeeid
order by num_invoice desc;
```

Comment: Am I reading that correctly? You put a whole query before the left outer join as the place you're pulling it from and then you called it ic?

Comment: Yes, I am selecting from employees and outer join the sub query result that gives me the invoice count per employee. I'm calling this subquery result ic for "invoices counted", but you could of course use any other name that is more readable to you.

Comment: It is very common to join subqueries by the way. After all, a query result is again a table, which you can join. In those DBMS that support the `WITH` clause (MySQL does so since version 8), you can create these ad-hoc views before the real query, which many people consider even more readable.